# Prebid - Index video outstream configuration with multiple playerSize in bidders

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

I would like to create an adUnit video outstream with multiple playserSizes for Index (documentation [there](https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/bidders/ix.html)

At first I thought to put the playerSize at the adUnit level, but because I want to define multiple playerSizes, I decided to move it at bidder level in  `params > video > playerSize`. Nonetheless it does not work whereas in the documentation it is written

````
If you are using Index’s outstream player and have placed the video object at the bidder level, you must include the Index required parameters at the bidder level``` (link above)

Here is my prebid configuration

```javascript
{
    "code": slotCode,
    "sizes": [[1,1],[300,250],[160,600],[300,600],[640,360]],
    "bids": [
        {
            "bidder": "criteo",
            "params": {
                "networkId": networkId,
                "video": {
                    "playerSize": [640, 480],
                    "skip": 0,
                    "playbackmethod": 1,
                    "placement": 1,
                    "mimes": [
                        "video/mp4"
                    ],
                    "maxduration": 30,
                    "api": [
                        1,
                        2
                    ],
                    "protocols": [
                        2,
                        3
                    ]
                }
            },
            "userId": {...},
            "userIdAsEids": [...],
            "crumbs": {...}
        },
        {
            "bidder": "index",
            "params": {
                "siteId": siteId,
                "size": [
                    640,
                    360
                ],
                "video": {
                    "playerSize": [640, 480],
                    "h": 640,
                    "w": 360,
                    "protocols": [
                        2,
                        3,
                        5,
                        6
                    ],
                    "minduration": 5,
                    "maxduration": 30,
                    "mimes": [
                        "video/mp4",
                        "application/javascript"
                    ],
                    "playerSize": [
                        640,
                        360
                    ]
                }
            },
            "userId": {... },
            "userIdAsEids": [...],
            "crumbs": {...}
        }
    ],
    "mediaTypes": {
        "video": {
            "context": "outstream"
        }
    },
    "pubstack": {...}
}
````

If I use this configuration, I got this error

```
ERROR: IX Bid Adapter: bid size is not included in ad unit sizes or player size.
```

Even if my playerSize for `index` ([640, 360]) is in the adUnit sizes.

I wonder if it is possible for an adUnit to have multiple payerSizes?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation it says it is possible. Like this:

```
var adUnits = [{
    code: 'video-ad-unit',
    mediaTypes: {
        video: {
            context: 'outstream',
            playerSize: [[640, 480], [300, 250], [400, 300]]
        }
    },
    bids: [{
        // your bidder specifics here
    }]
}];
```

Notes:

1. I see a sizes parameter in your setup which I don’t understand what it actually is.
2. If you still have trouble with IX errors you could try to create 2 adunits with the same code name but different setups [https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/adunit-reference.html#:~:text=It's%20ok%20to%20have%20multiple,e.g.&text=In%20this%20example%2C%20bidderA%20gets,while%20bidderB%20gets%20only%20banner](https://docs.prebid.org/dev-docs/adunit-reference.html#:%7E:text=It%27s%20ok%20to%20have%20multiple,e.g.&text=In%20this%20example%2C%20bidderA%20gets,while%20bidderB%20gets%20only%20banner).